# how to include secret.json files in SAM template.yml

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, serverless, aws-sam

In my previous application, I work with a serverless framework but now I want to use sam template.

when I used serverless I include **secret.json** in one section and used multiple places like this way **${self:custom.secrets.AWS_ID}**.

My sample code:

```
custom:
  secrets: ${file(secrets.json)}
  tableName: ${self:custom.secrets.DB_TABLE_NAME}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  environment:
    JWT_SECRET: ${self:custom.secrets.JWT_SECRET}
    AWS_ID: ${self:custom.secrets.AWS_ID}
    DB_TABLE_NAME: ${self:custom.secrets.DB_TABLE_NAME}
```

Now my question is, how can I include **secret.json** and use multiple places in sam template.yml file